# ASP.NET Web API on .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I have ASP.NET web api project created on .NET v 4.5
I later i was decided to change framework to 4.0
After changing i got an error. VS can not regognize types and namespaces althougt all required  librariesare referenced.
It does not happen to newly creted test API project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check that the dlls you are referencing are for version 4.0 and not 4.5, could be you are still referencing 4.5 libraries which won't work with .net 4.

Comment: thanks. i created the project from scratch and simply copied all necessary files